# AWS Oracle RDS - Multiple port configuration

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, oracle-net-services

First of all apologies if my question is too silly.

We have an AWS Oracle RDS which is listening on 1521 for plain text authentication and it is working fine. But we are trying to add an additional port (2484) for TCPS/SSL. We have enabled both tcp ports.

Is it possible to have one Oracle instance listening on multiple ports? I can't seem to find any documentation on enabling RDS to listen on multiple ports. Can anyone please point me to the right direction? Also, do i need to do any kind of port forwarding on the VPC?

Thanks so much for your time. If my question is too vague please let me know and I will try to explain.

Comment: The listener can handle both TCP and TCPS, oracle-base shows how here, but no idea on what RDS will let you do with your sqlnet and listener.ora files https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/configure-tcpip-with-ssl-and-tls-for-database-connections

Comment: In RDS, you can do this by adding the `SSL` option to the option group. It will ask for a port number. See this RDS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.html

Comment: Quick update. Our configuration was right. It was listening on both 1521 and 2484. The issue was client certificate wallet. In the end got it working by creating a wallet with orapki and setting connection from sql plus with tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora. Thanks everyone for your help.